# JFrame is not appearing consistently once JTable was added

Tags: java, swing

I am currently trying to include a JTable to my JPanel. I was not having any problems with my code previously until I started to code the table. Sometimes when I run my program everything will appear, sometimes just the panels appear, and sometimes/majority of the time nothing will appear. I just don't understand why it is not consistent. There are no errors in the console. I have included below my ViewPage.java, Page.java, and Main.java.

`

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ViewPage extends Page implements ActionListener
  {

    JPanel panel1, panel2, panel3;
    JLabel searchLabel, repairsLabel, dateLabel;
    JButton goButton, recentButton, oldestButton, homeButton;
    JComboBox dropDown;
    JTextField textField;
    JTable tabel;
    JScrollPane scrollpane;
    
    public ViewPage()
    {
      panel1 = new JPanel();
      panel1.setBackground(Color.blue);
      panel1.setBounds(0,0,1280,120);

      panel2 = new JPanel();
      panel2.setBackground(Color.green);
      panel2.setBounds(0,120,1280,480);

      panel3 = new JPanel();
      panel3.setBackground(Color.red);
      panel3.setBounds(0,600,1280,120);

      //Panel 1 components
      repairsLabel = new JLabel("Repairs");
      repairsLabel.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 50));
      
      searchLabel = new JLabel("Search :");
      searchLabel.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 25));

      goButton = new JButton("GO");
      goButton.setFocusable(false);
      goButton.addActionListener(this);

      textField = new JTextField();

      String[] filters = {" ", "customerID", "First_Name", "Last_Name"};
      dropDown = new JComboBox(filters);
      dropDown.addActionListener(this);
      
      panel1.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
      GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

      gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
      gbc.insets = new Insets(1, 10, 1, 0);
      gbc.weightx = 5.5;
      gbc.gridx = 0;
      gbc.gridy = 0;
      panel1.add(repairsLabel, gbc);

      gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
      gbc.weightx = 0.5;
      gbc.gridx = 1;
      gbc.gridy = 0;
      panel1.add(searchLabel, gbc);

      gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
      gbc.insets = new Insets(1, 10, 1, 50);
      gbc.weightx = 3;
      gbc.gridx = 2;
      gbc.gridy = 0;
      panel1.add(dropDown, gbc);

      gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
      gbc.insets = new Insets(1, 10, 1, 50);
      gbc.gridx = 3;
      gbc.gridy = 0;
      gbc.ipadx = 100; 
      panel1.add(textField, gbc);

      gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
      gbc.insets = new Insets(1, 10, 1, 100);
      gbc.gridx = 4;
      gbc.gridy = 0;
      gbc.ipadx = 1; 
      panel1.add(goButton, gbc);

      
      //Panel 2 components
      panel2.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

      String[][] data = new String[50][8];
      String[] headings = {"customer_ID", "Date", "First Name", "Last Name", "Phone #", "OS", "PC Type", "Problem"};
      
      JTable table = new JTable(data, headings);
      table.setEnabled(false);
      table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(1000,400));
      table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

      scrollpane = new JScrollPane(table);

      panel2.add(scrollpane);

      //Panel 3 componets
      panel3.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
      GridBagConstraints gbc2 = new GridBagConstraints();

      dateLabel = new JLabel("Date Filter: ");
      dateLabel.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 25));

      recentButton = new JButton("Most Recent");
      oldestButton = new JButton("Oldest");

      homeButton = new JButton("Home");

      gbc2.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
      gbc2.insets = new Insets(1, 10, 1, 0);
      gbc2.weightx = 5.5;
      gbc2.gridx = 0;
      gbc2.gridy = 0;
      panel3.add(dateLabel, gbc);
      

      frame.add(panel1);
      frame.add(panel2);
      frame.add(panel3);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
      if (e.getSource() == dropDown)
      {
        System.out.println(dropDown.getSelectedItem());
      }
    }
  }
```

`

`

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public abstract class Page
  {
    private final static int pageWidth = 1280;
    private final static int pageHeight = 720;
    
    protected JFrame frame;

    public Page()
    {
      frame = new JFrame();

      frame.setTitle("Computer Repair Store");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.setSize(pageWidth, pageHeight);
      frame.setLayout(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public int getpageWidth()
    {
      return pageWidth;
    }

    public int getpageHeight()
    {
      return pageHeight;
    }
  }
```

`

`

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ViewPage viewPage = new ViewPage();
    
  }
}
```

`

Ouput:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PW736.png)

This is what I am expecting to output which has only appeared 2-3 times out of the 50 times I have tried running the program.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1OWT.png)

Comment: You're using `setBounds` on the three `JPanels`.  Set the three `JPanels` `preferredSize` instead and use the `JFrame's` default `BorderLayout` to place the three `JPanels`.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.

Comment: You are using a null layout on the frame. Don't do that.

Comment: null layout is __wrong__!

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I changed the setBounds to preferredSize, also removed the setLayout(null) in my Page.java. Still nothing is appearing. https://replit.com/@Minich-221-Fall-2022/Final-Project-Interactive-Bar-Chart-ColeHadley?v=1#ViewPage.java

Comment: Try cutting the `frame.setVisible(true);` from the **Page** class and paste this *under* the `ViewPage viewPage = new ViewPage();` code line within the `main()` method of the **Main** class: `viewPage.frame.setVisible(true);`. Do consider using anything other than a **null** layout as suggested and use the `JFrame#pack()` method as well.

Comment: @DevilsHnd I believe the setVisible was the problem. Thank you so much :)